# Handy role title for someone managing the development and requirements processes

Tags: recruitment

We need to recruit someone who has experience in software development processes, i.e., from requirements management to delivery and maintenance (but not operations and systems administration), *maybe* an experienced developer. Additionally, the way we collect and manage requirements, together with the business departments, needs to be redesigned and implemented as to support the pursued (new) development approach, which may be done successfully by a good *business analyst* or the like. Naturally, we see this in the hands of the same one person, and we only have the budget for one new employment. Important note: the position is not linked to a particular team or project, since we rather see it as a *staff position*, with few (if any) "subordinates". Also, *no software architecture(s)* shall be covered.

For the former aspect, role titles such as "development coordinator" have already been proposed; for the latter, we currently have "requirements manager". But we need *one* role title that describes both aspects.

Comment: Look up "business analyst" on linkedin. See from a sample of the profiles listed there if "business analyst" fits your description. Given the inherent vagueness of "business analyst", you will have to provide a job description  anyway.

Comment: BA's don't tend to have great Dev skills from my experience, not because they can't but because those development skills aren't always in alignment with what BAs do on a daily basis. Business Analysists tend to go offsite to meet clients a lot etc. You want a developer who is *primarily* a developer. If they're a BA as well, unless they are *very* experienced, one of those sides will suffer. OP doesn't want to touch architecture, but that's what they're asking for. They want a solutions architect.

Comment: Thank you - how much focus would a solutions architect put on the "how" part of requirements analysis? Although I'm usually cautious with the word "architect", I like it more in combination with "solution". Sounds like "we get something done". And really, we need to do something about the methodology of the "touch points" of business and development: how to know what software (change) is needed, and how to deliver results. I know this is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the best starting point for you would be [software engineer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineer). What you describe is someone who has knowledge of or exposure to nearly all aspects of [software engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering), but particularly what is referred to in the Wikipedia article as requirements engineering, software engineering management, software engineering process, and software engineering tools and methods. It sounds like you're particularly interested in someone with expertise in [business process improvement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_improvement) or [process management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_management), but with particular expertise in the software field.

I'm a little concerned, though, when you say that you aren't interested in covering software architectures. [Enterprise Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_architecture) is not just the technical architecture and design of software systems, but also how teams form around the work. If you wanted to enable something like [product line engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_product_line), that would likely be not only process changes, but also organizational changes to support it. A role that you describe would have to be involved across all software development activities.

Comment: Enterprise Architecture sounds promising. We want to avoid a "technical" role title because we already have a couple of skilled people, and we need them to accept this person as someone who *supports* them and their work process, instead of opposing à la "so this guy is going to tell us how to do our work". It's really also a "bridge" between the "IT guys" / software team on the one hand, and the business people on the other.

Comment: @André In that case, I'd focus on business process improvement, with experience in software development. There are a lot of buzzwords and keywords floating around: Capability Maturity Model Integration (CMMI), Lean Software Development, Six Sigma for Software, Rational Unified Process, Scrum, Disciplined Agile Delivery, Crystal, Enterprise Unified Process, Team Software Process...the list goes on. What you do want to avoid, though, is someone pushing a particular model or methodology without understanding your business and the operating environment. Very rarely does one fit out of the box.

Comment: Very interesting - maybe we should call the role "Software development process manager" - and the methods and models you propose may serve as good "inspiration" or even (formal) base. Thanks!

Comment: @André I would be careful with the word "manager". That, to some, would imply that they have direct reports (that is, they are a manager). Although they are managing a process, it's not explicitly false, but it could be misleading. If this group grows, however, the leader would likely be a "manager" and the other people would likely be "process improvement engineers" or "process improvement specialists".

Comment: That's also true. I begin to feel we should use a rather short term, not using "manager", and really describe the tasks explicitly, as suggested before. "Architect" sounds a bit too "academic" to me, in the sense that they don't focus on something that actually works in "real life". Please don't get me wrong. As opposed, I do like the "engineer" term, which sounds like "hands-on" work. With "processes", it seems to be used more in the manufacturing domain. "Software engineer" is what you said in the first place  :-)

Comment: @André Yes, you do need to be careful with the term "process engineer". It means very different things to software and manufacturing. In fact, it even has special connotations with respect to chemical engineering. Hence, "process improvement" tends to be more specific. I do think the writing of the job posting is far more important, as long as the title is close enough to not turn people off from reading the description because they don't think they are qualified.